# __str__ Method returning sets vertically Python

Tags: python, string, class, methods

I'm trying to implement a **str** method inside of a class called matrix
my current code is

class Matrix(object):

```
def __init__(self):  # no modification is needed for this method, but you may modify it if you wish to
    '''Create and initialize your class attributes.'''
    self._matrix = []
    self._rooms = 0

def read_file(self,fp):  #fp is a file pointer
    '''Build an adjacency matrix that you read from a file fp.'''

    rooms = fp.readline()

    rooms = int(rooms)

    self._matrix= [set() for _ in range(rooms+1)]

    for line in fp:
        line=line.strip()
        item=line.split()
        item2=int(item[0])
        item3=int(item[1])
        self._matrix[item2].add(item3)
        self._matrix[item3].add(item2)
    return self._matrix

def __str__(self):
    '''Return the matrix as a string.'''
    s=''
    matrix=self._matrix
    for n in range(len(matrix)-1):
        s=s+"{}:{} ".format(n+1,matrix[n+1])
    return s
```

currently when i call the str method by print(Matrix()) i get the output:
1:{2} 2:{1, 3} 3:{2, 4} 4:{3, 5} 5:{4, 6} 6:{5}

what i want printed is:

1: 2

2: 1 3

3: 2 4

4: 3 5

5: 4 6

6: 5

any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly adding the string representation of the set to your output string, convert each item of your set to a string, and join the elements to a new string with `" "` as a separator. Add a newline (`"\n"`) to each line.

```
s+= "%d: %s\n" % (n+1, " ".join([str(x) for x in matrix[n+1]]))
```

Comment: *cough* `" ".join(...)`

Comment: you don't need string for this, just do something like `'" "'.join(str(x) for x in matrix[n + 1])`

Comment: im getting a  module 'string' has no attribute 'join' error?

Comment: indeed `" ".join(...)` is more pythonic, no need to import the string module